# Julia lang - How to read JSON from HTTP URL

Tags: json, julia, http-get

**Goal**

How to read a JSON from HTTP URL using Julia-lang?

Answer (score 5):

**Code**

```
#Importing Requests package
Pkg.add("Requests")
using Requests.get;

import JSON;

url = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20DaysRange%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22EBAY%22%29%20&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env&format=json";

#Reads the data from HTTP URL
es = get(url);

j = JSON.parse(es.data)


#Prints the data from JSON
print(j["query"]["results"]["quote"])
```

[Git Gist](https://gist.github.com/nrshrivatsan/974f19f9779a81c2c5f6)

Answer (score 5):

Alternative, using HTTP (found [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-read-json-from-html/3664/5)):

```
using HTTP, JSON

resp = HTTP.get("https://api.github.com/users/juliohm")
str = String(resp.body)
jobj = JSON.Parser.parse(str)
```