# How to read a JSON file from URL into a DataFrame in Julia?

Tags: json, dataframe, julia

I am trying to do the following. I have a url that links to a JSON file containing numerical data. I would like to read this data into a DataFrame. I have been following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687599/julia-lang-how-to-read-json-from-http-url) on how to read from a url into a JSON object. But, after running this code:

```
resp = HTTP.get("[url here]")   
str = String(resp.body)   jobj =
JSON.Parser.parse(str)
```

I get this error:

> Expected 'r' here
> Line: 0
> Around: ...timestamp,open,high,lo...
> _________^

Note, this code does run for a different JSON file that I used to test it. Next, after this step, I have tried following [this](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/dataframes-best-way-to-import-from-json-format-file/29946) advice on how to read a JSON file into a DataFrame. However, after running this code:

```
df = DataFrame(jsontable(jobj))
```

I get this error:

```
MethodError: no method matching read(::Dict{String,Any})
```

This step does not work on file I used to test the previous code. I appreciate any help with the above code or any new approaches to do this. Also I should mention I am very much a beginner when it comes to coding anything outside of data analysis. Thank you for any help!

EDIT: The first part of the code now runs correctly (I had the wrong URL). And I am getting a new error when I run the second part of the code. After running:

```
df = DataFrame(jsontable(jobj))
```

I get the error:

```
MethodError: no method matching read(::Dict{String,Any})
```

UPDATE: I ended up writing a function that is able to parse the file. It only extracts two of the columns but for now that works.

```
function json_df_parse(jobj)
    timestamp = collect(keys(jobj));close = String[];
    for key in timestamp
        jobj2 = jobj[key]
        push!(close,jobj2["4. close"])
    end
    df = DataFrame(timestamp = timestamp, close = close)
    return df
end
```

Here is a sample of what the JSON file looks like:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Intraday (1min) open, high, low, close prices and volume",
        "2. Symbol": "XXXX",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2021-02-22 20:00:00",
        "4. Interval": "1min",
        "5. Output Size": "Full size",
        "6. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Time Series (1min)": {
        "2021-02-22 20:00:00": {
            "1. open": "4.2800",
            "2. high": "4.2800",
            "3. low": "4.2800",
            "4. close": "4.2800",
            "5. volume": "149"
        },
        "2021-02-22 19:59:00": {
            "1. open": "4.2400",
            "2. high": "4.2500",
            "3. low": "4.2400",
            "4. close": "4.2500",
            "5. volume": "999"
```

Comment: can you post a link to the file that is causing problem please?

Comment: unfortunately no bc it has sensitive information - but I was able to get the first part of the code to run! So the file now reads in correctly. But I'm still not able to get it into a data frame. I'll update the question ...

Comment: Are you using JSON3.jl?

Comment: After edit: you will need to create an empty `DataFrame` and parse your JSON one Time series element at a time and use `push!` to add that elements one by one.

Answer (score 1):

### First example - 1 element in json

I think the following should work:

```
using JSON, HTTP, DataFrames

url = "https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/pubticker/btcusd"
result = HTTP.request("GET", url)
json_result = JSON.parse(String(result.body))

df = DataFrame(json_result)
```

I get:

```
1×8 DataFrame
 Row │ ask      bid      high     last_price  low      mid      timestamp          volume         
     │ String   String   String   String      String   String   String             String         
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 47588.0  47554.0  55000.0  47588.0     45000.0  47571.0  1614113583.333932  33063.93120034
```

### Second example - many elements

Here is a second example, more complicated (and probably not the best way to do it, but it works here...):

```
using JSON, HTTP, DataFrames

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rbell01824/djangopages_2/5b22451b68320b9b0d4aaae01fcbc0d357d43acd/git/test_data/graphtestdata/countries.json";
result = HTTP.request("GET", url)
json_result = JSON.parse(String(result.body))
dfi = [DataFrame(;[Symbol(k)=>v for (k,v) in json_result[i]["fields"]]...) for i in 1:length(json_result)]
df = reduce(vcat, dfi)
```

Result:

```
238×8 DataFrame
 Row │ a3   population  country_size  a2   num    country_name              infant_mortality  life_expectancy 
     │ Any  Int64       Int64         Any  Int64  String                    Float64           Float64         
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ AFG    29757566        652230  AF       4  Afghanistan                         123.89            49.33
   2 │ ALB     2994667         27398  AL       8  Albania                              14.61            77.41
   3 │ DZA    34994937       2381741  DZ      12  Algeria                              25.81            74.5
   4 │ ASM       67242           199  AS      16  American Samoa                        9.66            74.21
   5 │ AND       84825           468  AD      20  Andorra                               3.8             82.43
   6 │ AGO    17544728       1246700  AO      24  Angola                               85.28            54.14
...
```

Comment: This worked better than what I had originally, but I am getting a dataframe which has two columns - the first column is correct but the the second column contains a Dictionary which has the remaining columns and values in key value pairs

Answer (score 1):

Consider this JSON file:

```json
{ "id":[1,2,3],
"vals":[1, 2.1, 3],
"v2":[4.1,null,6.3],
"v3":["7","8",null] }
```

To make it reproducible I have placed it under https://szufel.pl/stackoverflowdemo.json

Now you can do:

```
julia> using DataFrames, JSONTables, HTTP

julia> r = HTTP.get("https://szufel.pl/stackoverflowdemo.json");

julia> df = DataFrame(jsontable(r.body))
3×4 DataFrame
 Row │ id     vals  v2         v3
     │ Int64  Real  Float64?   String?
─────┼─────────────────────────────────
   1 │     1     1        4.1  7
   2 │     2   2.1  missing    8
   3 │     3     3        6.3  missing
```

Comment: I tried this and got the error ```ArgumentError: input `JSON3.Object` must only have `JSON3.Array` values to be considered a table```. I think it may be an issue with the way the particular JSON file I have is laid out. It seems to be a dictionary where the keys are the values of the first column and the values are each dictionaries of their own containing the key values pairs of the rest of the columns and their values.

Comment: I think this is all what can be done without seeing the actual data. Perhaps you could produce same data sample. There is no one general solution on "how to process data"

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. I can post some of the data - I'll edit the original post to add it.